# 7zip update split archive

Tags: 7-zip

**I am using the gui**

So I have a split archive in format

```
archive.7z.01
archive.7z.02
archive.7z.03
```

I want to update them to match the folder being compressed but I get the error "The file exists"

Answer (score 1):

7zip does not have this functionality for multi-file archives.